# how to solve quadratic objective in CPLEX optimization studio?

Tags: optimization, cplex

I've implemented my problem in IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio.

Now i would like to modify the objective function to be quadratic and solve the problem. However, it shows an Error 5002:objective is not convex.->problem can be solved to global optimality with solution target 3->.

I have read the user guide and manual and the different topics in stackoverflow, and I beleive version 12.8 can solve mixed-integer quadratic problems.

```
    modify my objective from this 

        dexpr float overallcost[f in cars] = holdingTime[f];

    to this

    dexpr float overallcost[f in cars] = holdTime[f]*holdTime[f];
```

Error 5002:objective is not convex.->problem can be solved to global optimality with solution target 3->.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by the error message you should try setting the solution target parameter to 3 to force CPLEX to solve your model.

More details about this can be found in [this chapter of the user manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/cont_optim/qp/02_convexity_defn.html) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/OptimalityTarget.html) is the documentation of the respective parameter.

To set this parameter in the IDE create/add a settings file to your project and then go to
`Mathematical Programming` -> `General` -> `Type of solution to compute`
and choose "Global optimal solution".

Answer (score 1):

See

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/OptimalityTarget.html

In order to set that parameter in order to solve quadratic objectives.

In your model, you may add:

```
execute
{
cplex.optimalitytarget=3;
}
```